# Address Sanitizer doesn't compile with an app with DriverKit target

Tags: ios, xcode, address-sanitizer, xcode15, driverkit

We got an iOS app with two targets, the main target and an DriverKit extension target.

If I want to activate the Address Sanitizer in the scheme for the main app:

[image: AddressSanitizerEnabled]

I would get an error:

```
File cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_driverkit_dynamic.dylib in '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_driverkit_dynamic.dylib'
```

I assume this is because driverkit doesn't allow Address Sanitizer, because if I remove the DriverExtension target, the app will compile just fine.

I think I could set up manually the Address Sanitizer with this compiler flag:

```
-fsanitize=address
```

I wonder if there is way using the compiler flags manually in the Building settings so I can set up the Address Sanitizer only for the main target but not for the extension.

Would this be possible or would this run into other problems?